# Phonegap notification

Tags: cordova, notifications, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to use phonegap notification to show users a football game is about to start. I cannot find any documentation for pushing notification depending on time. Is this possible to do and if it is possible where can I find this information.

Comment: You can use phonegap local notification plugin